# Adding custom Header and Footer in CSV generated using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am writing the results of a query to a CSV file. However I am looking to add custom header `(H|10|27)` and footer `(F|<row_count>)`

I read related posts at SO but i couldn't find anything specific to python and pandas. Neither the documentation refers to this.

I am not sure how to go about that:
My code:

```
cs = connect_snowflake().cursor()
    try:
        cs.execute("select * from <Tables> where id in (20, 24,61);")
        datas = cs.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
        print(df.head(10))
        df.to_csv('P202461.csv', sep='|', header=False)
    finally:
        cs.close()
```

The footer here should be the total count of rows. Which I can fetch in a separate variable and pass it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you have a real need for pandas in this case. 
Try the standard [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Something like this should work:

```
import csv

def output_query_to_csv(query, filename='P202461.csv):
    with connect_snowflake() as conn, open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8) as csv_out:
        cs = conn.cursor()
        cs.execute(query)
        datas = cs.fetchall()
        writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter='|')
        header = ('H', '10', '27')
        footer = ('F', len(datas))
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(datas)
        writer.writerow(footer)
```